# Render Header level interactive charts for dataframes in Streamlit

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, streamlit

I’ve been working on kaggle for a while and wondered how can we acheive the header level charts in streamlit.
The charts take aggregate of the corresponding column data and render charts.
Then the charts glide over the dataframe.
Refer screenshots below.
would love a feature/component/workaround for this!

[Kaggle screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L9kr7.png)

Also came across a similar functionality on akkio.com

[Akkio screenshort](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rCKy4.png)

I tried modifying the library level functions but it was directionless

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.